# Одновременное изменение данных в моей программе и в Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

Всем привет, возможно ли открыть один и тот же xls файл в Экселе и в моей программе, и чтобы при изменении данных в одной программе, в другой они изменялись сразу же, на лету, без переоткрытия файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я знаю нельзя.

Если откроете в программе, а потом сами откроете файл, то вам скажут, что в файле уже кто-то сидит и предложат открыть его в ReadOnly.

Откроете вы раньше, тогда программа свалится с ошибкой.

Можно поэксперементировать с общим доступом, но даже в этом случае пользователь будет видеть изменения только при сохранении.